# How to start a lockscreen activity instantaneously after reboot?

Tags: android-activity, service, broadcastreceiver, lockscreen

I want to start a lockscreen activity after device reboot side by side with the startup notifications like Messages,Viber notifications,Whatsapp etc.How to do this ??.I have made a broadcast receiver which receives BOOT_COMPLETED action and upon that it starts a service that registers the same receiver again with Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF and Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON intent filter and that receiver starts the lockscreen activity.Here is my code:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" ></uses-permission>

<receiver>
       <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
       </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

and of course I declared the service in the manifest.

Here is my Broadcast Receiver class

```
public class LockScreenBroadCastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  Log.d("BroadCastReceiver", "ReceivedIntent");

  if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {

  Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, LockScreenActivity.class);
  myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);

  if (!LockScreenActivity.isActivityRunning) {
    context.startActivity(myIntent);
  }else{
    Log.d("BroadCasrReceiver","LockScreenActivity is running");
  }

  }else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
  Log.v("LockScreenBroadReceiver","boot completed");
  Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context,LockScreenService.class);             
  context.startService(startServiceIntent);
 }
}
}
```

and the service class :

public class LockScreenService extends Service {

```
LockScreenBroadCastReceiver broadCastReciever;
public static boolean isRunning;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    isRunning = true;
    registerReceiver();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    isRunning = false;
    unregisterReceiver(broadCastReciever);
    Log.d("LockScreenReceiver", "ReceiverUnregistered");
    sendBroadcast(new Intent("RestartLockScreenService"));
}

private void registerReceiver(){
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    broadCastReciever = new LockScreenBroadCastReceiver();
    registerReceiver(broadCastReciever,intentFilter);
    Log.d("LockScreenReceiver", "ReceiverRegistered");
 }
}
```

This approach is working.However,It's very slow as the broadcast receiver listens to BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast which waits until the device is fully up and working.So,you may lock and unlock the phone several times before you get the lockscreen working.Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *intentFilter* instace of **BootComplate** in manifist like this:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.unfortunately,this didn't do the trick,there is still some delay after boot and the user has to lock and unlock the phone 2-3 times before my custom lock screen activity appears.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It was fixed by including

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

on the receiver. The is a slight delay of 6 seconds on reboot which I'm trying to narrow down.

I hope this works for you

Comment: Thank you for help! . This is the same case with me, now I have an average delay of several seconds as you mentioned. I also use this xml tag. I'm trying to get better result by searching for some tutorials somewhere. I feel there are no much docs regarding this topic. If you find a good one, pls forward it to me.